# creating an endpoint that when called, the user's account will be verified in Laravel Api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, verify

I am working with laravel API and I want that when I type this endpoint "verify" as in " http://.../api/verify" the users email automatically gets verified. This is my code so far, but it isn't working. It is giving me this error "message": "", please let me know if you have any idea on how I can get this done. Thank you

this is my first trial

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function (){    
    Route::get('/verify', [VerifyEmailController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');
    
});
```

and this is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;


class VerifyEmailController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function __invoke(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME.'?verified=1');
        }

        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME.'?verified=1');
    }
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
       
        if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response(['message'=>'Already Verified']);
        }

        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }

        return response(['message'=>'Successfully Verified']);
    }
}
```

this is my second trial

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function (){    
    Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
        $request->fulfill();
    
    })->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify'); 
    
});
```

this is my last trial

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function (){    
    Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');

});
```

and this is the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;
 
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

    public function verify($id, Request $request) {
        if (! $request->hasValidSignature()) {
            return response(['message'=>'invalid_email_verification_url']);
        }

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        if (!$user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            $user->markEmailAsVerified();
        }

        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Im a bit unclear on what your trying ot do but from what i understand a logged in user will hit a route that will verify their email?

Comment: @yeak yes that is what i want to do

Comment: So why not just make a route in and in your controller if the user is logged in you can access the user email or id like so Auth::user()->email and you can check if the input email is the same as the user email?